# NgbModal not being mocked correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, bootstrap-modal

having an issue trying to mock NgbModal. Whatever I do I can't properly mock NgbModal, so when this.modalService.open is called in the delete modal component, it doesn't return what I want it to. Also the test "Modal Opened" fails due to modalService.open not being called at all. Am new to jasmine & angular so hoping someone has some insight.

Thanks for any help.

```
describe('DeleteModalComponent', () => {

  let component: DeleteModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DeleteModalComponent>;
  let modalService: NgbModal;
  let modalRef: NgbModalRef;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const toastSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ToastrService', ['error']);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        DeleteModalComponent,
        GroupDeleteModalComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        NgbModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        NgbActiveModal,
        { provide: ToastrService, useValue: toastSpy },
      ],
    }).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [GroupDeleteModalComponent],
      },
    }).compileComponents();
  });
  beforeEach(() => {
    modalService = TestBed.inject(NgbModal) as jasmine.SpyObj<NgbModal>;
    modalRef = modalService.open(GroupDeleteModalComponent);
    spyOn(modalService, 'open').and.returnValue(modalRef);
    spyOn(console, 'log').and.callThrough();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeleteModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

    it('Modal Opened', () => {
      component.open();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(modalService.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});


@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete-modal',
  templateUrl: './delete-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete-modal.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbModalConfig, NgbModal],
})
export class DeleteModalComponent {
  @Output()
  readonly notify: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  open() {
    const modalRef: NgbModalRef = this.modalService.open(GroupDeleteModalComponent);
    modalRef.result.then((value) => {
      this.notify.emit(value);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      this.toastr.error('Delete failed.');
    });
  }
}
```